# How can I change "Connection Timeout" connection string on unixODBC connector to MS SQL Server?

Tags: unixodbc

I want to increase my connection string "Connection Timeout" property in a unixODBC set up I have connecting a HANA DB to MS SQL Server- which I installed out of the box, and I only know how to configure it via the .odbc.ini.

Would anyone know how I can increase the Connection Timeout setting from default in the .odbc.ini?

```
[SOURCENAME]
DRIVER=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2260.0
ServerName=<server>:<port>
Database=<DBName>
ConnectionTimeout=????
```